# Initialise egorkhmelev jslider programmatically

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm using egorkhmelev's 
https://github.com/egorkhmelev/jslider (dated October 10, 2012) but have been unable to initialise a jslider instance programmatically.  I'm also using jQuery 1.9.1 and the full jQuery-ui 1.10.3 (both minified)

I have seen in Egor's documentation and on this site references to `$(elementID).slider("value", value, value)` but when I put that in the document.ready function in the subsequent statement to building the jslider, jQuery 1.9.1 reports

```
Error: cannot call methods on slider prior to initialisation; attempted to call method 'value'
```

This error is not generated if I move the `.slider("value"...)` line of code outside the document.ready function but then it doesn't do anything either.  I have tried `.`**j**`slider("value"...)` inside and outside the doc.ready but although it does not generate an error it does not set the default value either.

I've also tried specifying a 'value' option in the jslider initialisation but this also has no effect.

Getting creative, I also tried

```
$('input[id=timeSlider]').val(defaultValue);
$('#timeSlider').slider("value",defaultValue);
```

and

```
$('#timeSlider').html($('#timeSlider').html().replace(/value=\d+/,'value='+defaultValue));
```

neither of which have any effect.  `.html()` within doc ready returns nothing.

I discovered that I had to include a `value=NN` parameter in the HTML otherwise I get an `uncaught exception: jquery.slider: INPUT element does not have a value.`

I have tried and I have searched for an answer but I haven't been able to solve this.  I apologise if I'm missing the obvious.

The HTML:

```
<span style="display: inline-block; width: 270px; padding: 1em 1em 1.5em 1em;">
<input id="timeSlider" type="slider" name="timeSlide" value=15 />
</span>
```

The Javascript (from doc ready function):

```
$('#timeSlider').jslider({
        from: 0,
        to: 600,
        heterogeneity: ['25/10', '50/20', '75/120'],
        step: 1,
        round: 1,
        limits:false,
        scale: ['∞', '|', 10, '|', '20', '|', 120, '|', 600],
        dimension: ' s',
        skin: "plastic",
        onstatechange: function (value) {
            defaultValue = value;
        }
    });
```

where `defaultValue` is a global variable.

Thank you.

Comment: the error means that you have to initialize the widget first before setting any options on it. 1: $(el).slider(); 2 : once that done you can set or get values like this : $(el).slider("value"...)

Comment: Thanks rusln.  I have tried that but the widget still takes whatever value is specified in the HTML.  I've tried using `.slider("value")` both in and after the doc ready but the effect is the same: no effect.  I have now noticed that jslider's `onstatechange` callback is called when the jslider is created and that seems to be setting the slider to the default HTML value.  I'm also confused about why I need to add a jQuery UI slider and jslider to the same HTML element.  If jslider uses jQuery-UI's slider, shouldn't I be setting the underlying slider's value through jslider?  Thanks again.

Comment: SOLVED!  `$('#helpTimeSlider').attr("value", defaultValue)` BEFORE initialising the jslider object.